# Separate ContourPlot3D generated planes

Tags: plotting

I use

```mathematica
ContourPlot3D[
 -7 - 12 x + 32 x^2 + 54 y - 28 x y - 67 y^2 + 16 z + 88 x z - 
   136 y z + 28 z^2 == 0,
 {x, -2, 2},
 {y, -2, 2},
 {z, -2, 2}]
```

get this

[image]

You can see that the two faces are staggered, and I want to separate them，likethis

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
z /. Solve[-7 - 12 x + 32 x^2 + 54 y - 28 x y - 67 y^2 + 16 z + 
  88 x z - 136 y z + 28 z^2 == 0, z] // Simplify // PowerExpand
Plot3D[Evaluate[%], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

> $\left\{\frac{1}{14} \left(-\sqrt{65} (2 x-5 y+1)-22 x+34 y-4\right),\frac{1}{14} \left(\sqrt{65} (2 x-5 y+1)-22 x+34 y-4\right)\right\}$
> [image]